# The compiler failed with error code -1073741502 for one page only

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I know there are numbers of discussion made for **The compiler failed with error code -1073741502** but mine is quite different.

For my ASP.NET web site it is for a particular .aspx  page (name Report.aspx) this error code generate.

### Steps to generate error

1. Load the Report.aspx (First time it will work fine)
2. Make some changes to Report.aspx. Html changes / CSS changes enough
3. Refresh the Report.aspx and the error come.

### Observation

I have notice for each time I rebuild website / solution / restart debugging the Report.aspx works fine for first time load and it become problem when I do some changes in that page (step 2).

### Things I try

- Restart Syste, IIS, AppPool
- Dedicated IIS user for Site (ref [C# compiler or Visual Basic .Net compilers fail with error code -1073741502 when generating assemblies for your ASP.net site](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2012/09/19/c-compiler-or-visual-basic-net-compilers-fail-with-error-code-1073741502-when-generating-assemblies-for-your-asp-net-site/))
- Disable all antivirus, Applicatin run check, Live Protection.

Any new suggenstions?

Comment: First you are getting a run-time error, not a compiler error. You have a very general error that indicates the was an error when executing the aspx.  You have to debug the code.  The is no quick answer to the issue.

Comment: @jdweng as I try to compile code using debugger but the compiler didn't reach to the debug point it just come up with this message.

Comment: If you read the link you provided carefully it says the dll is being executed.  So it is doing more than just compiling even though the error message says it is a compiler error.

Comment: @jdweng any clear way to dignosys this error because I tried using trace but it is not showing trace even due to this error.

Comment: Add additional code to aspx to give more diagnostic or start commenting out code to isolate issue.  It looks like the Report Refresh isn't working. So I would start there.

Comment: @jdweng it sound like something else. I have installed SpyBot and Malwarebytes but I doubt on SpyBot. It have feature for LIVE Protection and it is assumption due to this when csv.exe start working the SpyBot also start working and create issue. I will look again with this and SpyBot too and let you know so this can be helpful to others as well.

Comment: You could try a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark.